# Java Service Error - webMethods

Tags: webmethods

In a java service, without a function declaration, a function call is there and only compile time error comes. But the output is as expected with no run time errors. How is that possible? Can anyone please explain?

"The method functionName() is undefined" is the error it shows.

Below is the code.

```
     public static final void documentToStringVals(IData pipeline)
        throws ServiceException {

    // pipeline
    IDataCursor pipelineCursor = pipeline.getCursor();
    String success = "false";
    IData inputDoc = null;
    String outputValue = "";
    String headerYN = "N"; 
    boolean headerValue = false;
    String delimiter = ","; 
    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    if (pipelineCursor.first("inputDocument") ) {
        inputDoc = (IData) pipelineCursor.getValue();
    }
    else {
        throw new ServiceException("inputDocument is a required parameter");
    }

    if (pipelineCursor.first("delimiter") ) {
        delimiter = (String) pipelineCursor.getValue();
    }

    if (pipelineCursor.first("headerYN") ) {
        headerYN = (String) pipelineCursor.getValue();
    }
    if (headerYN.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
        headerValue = true;
    }

    try {

        outputValue = docValuesToString(inputDoc, headerValue, delimiter);  

        outputValue += newline;
        success = "true";
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in getting string from document: " + e.getMessage());
        pipelineCursor.insertAfter("errorMessage", e.getMessage());
    }
    pipelineCursor.insertAfter("success", success);
    pipelineCursor.insertAfter("outputValue", outputValue);
    pipelineCursor.destroy();
}
```

Comment: What version of WebMethods are you using?  Are you using Designer or Developer?  Are you sure the runtime is using the code in your service (confirm this by changing something and seeing if the change occurs at runtime - otherwise it may be executing and old .class file)?  Can you post the source code?

Comment: I am using 9.8 designer. The code is used and only by calling the function, value is assigned to the output variable. It throws the output as expected.

Comment: I have pasted the code. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted has no reference to "`functionName`", so I suspect there's a reference to it either in the shared code section or in another Java service in the same folder.  Given that all Java services in a folder get compiled into a single class, and therefore all those services need to be compiled together, this could cause the error message when you're compiling the service above.